# Why am I getting this DCPError?

Tags: quadratic-programming, cvxpy

I'm trying to optimize a binary portfolio vector to be greater than a benchmark using CVXPY.

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Generate a random non-trivial quadratic program.

n = 10 # number of options

np.random.seed(1)
mu = np.random.randn(n) # expected means
var_covar = np.random.randn(n,n) # variance-covariance matrix
var_covar = var_covar.T.dot(var_covar) # cont'd
bench_cov = np.random.randn(n) # n-length vector of cov(benchmark, returns)

lamd = 0.01 # risk tolerance

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.

x = cp.Variable(n, boolean=True)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(mu.T@x + lamd * (cp.quad_form(x, var_covar) - (2 * bench_cov.T@x))), [cp.sum(x) == 4])

prob.solve()
```

I get this error using CVXPY version 1.1.0a0 (downloaded directly from github):

> **DCPError**: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
>
> The objective is not DCP, even though each sub-expression is.
>
> You are trying to maximize a function that is convex.

From what I've read maximizing a convex function is very difficult, but I got this equation from a paper that solves the same equation using Gurobi's BQP solver. I figure I must be doing something wrong as I'm new to quadratic programming and CVXPY.

Thank you!

Comment: X-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58599059/6338725

Comment: Gurobi (and Cplex) automatically linearizes this problem using the same technique as detailed in my answer in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599059/why-am-i-getting-this-dcperror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cvxpy's rules for disciplined convex programming are listed [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html).

Notably, it states that:

> The DCP rules require that the problem objective have one of two forms:
>
> Minimize(convex)
>
> Maximize(concave)

Indeed, your program runs if we remove the `quad_form` and doesn't run if we leave only the `quad_form`:

```cpp
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(cp.quad_form(x, var_covar)), [cp.sum(x) == 4])
```

So it doesn't work because you are not obeying the rules of disciplined convex programming.

How can you solve this problem?

1. Fix the math. Maybe you made a mistake?
2. cvxpy's implementation of DCP is built from atoms, so any problem you want to solve must be expressible in this atoms. If you believe your program should be solvable by the techniques used by cvxpy, then perhaps you can rejigger your math to use a different set of atoms to express the same problem. (I think this is unlikely given the simplicity of the problem.) This might also be why Gurobi can solve the problem: it may have access to a more expansive set of inter-atom manipulations.
3. Don't use disciplined convex programming. That `boolean=True` means that you're already living in integer programming land. To my knowledge, DCP can't help you here.

**Edit**:

Perhaps the matrix in the paper you are reading is negative definite. In that case, you'd be maximizing a concave function, which is allowed. In this case, you've simply built your example wrong. Try this instead:

````py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Generate a random non-trivial quadratic program.

n = 10 # number of options

np.random.seed(1)
mu = np.random.randn(n) # expected means
# var_covar = np.random.randn(n,n) # variance-covariance matrix
# var_covar = var_covar.T.dot(var_covar) # cont'd
bench_cov = np.random.randn(n) # n-length vector of cov(benchmark, returns)

#Make a negative definite matrix
var_covar = -np.array(range(n))
var_covar = np.diag(var_covar)

lamd = 0.01 # risk tolerance

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.

x = cp.Variable(n)

#Ensure matrix is negative definite so we are maximizing a concave function
assert np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(var_covar) <= 0)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(cp.quad_form(x, var_covar)), [cp.sum(x) == 4])

prob.solve()
```
````

Comment: I really appreciate this response. Yes, I saw those rules. Honestly I don't really understand what convex/concave means in the context of a QP/LP. 1. That `quad_form` term looks like this in the paper $$x^T\Sigma x$$ Does that look like a place I should use `quad_form`? 2. I'll look through the atoms 3. Yeah, I have a boolean vector as the item I want to optimize.  I do have some other non-integer terms, so I guess it's MIP? I'm pretty new to the optimization area. Again, I appreciate your comment. Very helpful!

Comment: @George: I find it confusing as well. That is a quadratic form, though you'll notice that your $\Sigma$ matrix must also be positive definite before its convex. Convexity/concavity is something of a convention.

Comment: @George: Consider a parabola (it's a quad form in 2D). If it opens upward and you're minimizing, then there's a unique minimum. If it opens upward and you're maximizing, then there are two paths towards "maximum" and the only way from one path to the other is going through the minimum. That's the definition of non-convex. Mathematically, a convex space is one in which any path toward the maximum increases monotonically.

Comment: @George cvxpy uses the word "convex" to mean two things, which is why it is confusing. It calls a parabola opening up "convex" and a parabola opening down "concave". You've offered it a "convex" curve, but then asked for maximization, which is not a mathematically-convex problem.

Comment: But if your matrix was negative definite, you'd be in business.

Comment: @George: See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on convex, it makes sense we would need shapes with unique mins/maxs. Unfortunately that matrix is a variance-covariance matrix, which I think is always positive semi-definite?

Comment: @George I believe in the portfolio optimization problem, you likely want to be _minimizing_ that quadratic form, as the term gives you the estimated variance in the returns of your portfolio. If you maximized the quadratic form, you would expect your “optimal” portfolio to have very unpredictable returns, which doesn’t seem like what you would desire in a portfolio.

Comment: (Another way to express what I’m saying is that you want -lamb in the objective instead of +lamb)

Comment: @cdipaolo yeah, it may sound counter intuitive— but in this case I’m trying to create a portfolio to outperform a benchmark. Unfortunately my best portfolio has an expected mean BELOW the expected mean of the benchmark. Therefore I actually need to maximize the mean + variance to give myself the best chance of beating the benchmark.